# Angular JS - $http.delete "Syntax error on token '.' ,, (comma) expected " on Eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, http-request

Eclipse keeps telling the error on $http.delete, when other methods (like $http.put, $http.post) are not. What could it be?
For example, $http.put:

```
updateUser: function(user, id){
                return $http.put('http://localhost:8090/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/'+id, user)
                        .then(
                                function(response){
                                    return response.data;
                                }, 
                                function(errResponse){
                                    console.error('Error while updating user');
                                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                }
                        );
        }
```

And now, $http.delete

```
deleteUser: function(id){
                return $http.delete('http://localhost:8090/Spring4MVCAngularJSExample/user/'+id)
                        .then(
                                function(response){
                                    return response.data;
                                }, 
                                function(errResponse){
                                    console.error('Error while deleting user');
                                    return $q.reject(errResponse);
                                }
                        );
        }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Que tal fazer a pergunta em português?

Answer (score 1):

`delete` é uma palavra reservada no JavaScript, e alguns interpretadores têm problemas ao ler ela no meio de expressões (como o antigo Internet Explorer e provavelmente o interpretador do Eclipse).

O que você pode fazer para parar de receber esse erro é invocar o método de outra maneira:

```
$http({
  method: 'DELETE',
  url: 'http://exemplo.com'
})
.then(...);
```

> [$http.delete](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#delete) é um atalho para o código acima.

ou

```
$http['delete']('http://exemplo.com')
  .then(...);
```

Mas esse erro é só da IDE, o browser vai interpretar sem problemas, seja com o código acima ou da maneira que está agora.